# Spritekit motion track

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In my recent Spritekit project, I want a `node` which the user can move and it shows it movement track as below

I was thinking of using the `SKEmitterNode` to achieve that,but the particles aren't so "separate" from each other

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving behind x number of copies of your original sprite, but start an SKAction to fade the alpha to 0, and perhaps scale the size to 0 as well. Create a NSTimer to remove old sprites after a second or two.  place this code where you move your main sprite that you wiant a tail of

```
//copy the sprite that is moving around
let newSprite = theMovingNode.copy()

//fade and shrink our new sprite
newSprite.runAction(SKAction.FadeAlphaTo(0,duration:2.0))
newSprite.runAction(SKAction.ScaleTo(0,duration:2.0))

// create a timer to remove this sprite in 2 seconds
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("removeTailSprite:"), userInfo: newSprite, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Additionally, using either an action sequence or completion handler, you could add the removeFromParent action to the newSprite and not need the separate timer.

Comment: But there's another question, when I place the code above in the `touchMove:` or `update` method, I can't get the `presentedLayer` of the `SKNode`, instead I get the `model Layer` property of the `SKNode`, e.g,I move quickly from the top to the bottom, `theMovingNode` only changed a few time on its position property

Comment: @Thunk you're right, that would be the easier and more logical way to remove the old tail nodes, I'll change the code to add this.

Comment: @Lanston this is a common problem, and you might have to do some calculations and saving of previous touch locations. then you will need to draw the line between the previous point and the new point, and drop trailing images inbetween them. If you search around here you will see similar issues and their solutions